# Access in array in specific indices

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to access an array in a function, as far as I understand there is no Arraylists in Swift, so I am trying to use regular list:

```
  func findNearsetPoints(pointsArray: [Point] , myPoint: Point )-> Array <Point>{

    var twoPoint = [Point]()
    var minDist1:Double = DBL_MAX;
    var minDist2:Double = DBL_MAX;
    var distance:Double = 0

    for element in pointsArray{
        distance = getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(pointsArray[element], Point); //error 0
        if (distance < minDist1) {
            minDist1 = distance;
            twoPoint[1] = twoPoint[0];
            twoPoint[0] = pointsArray[element]; // error 1
        }
        else if (distance < minDist2) {
            minDist2 = distance;
            twoPoint[1] = pointsArray[element]; //error 1
        }
    }

    return twoPoint;
    }

    func getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(point1:Point , point2:Point )->Double{
        return 5; //TODO
    }
```

error 0:

> /Users/user/Desktop/proj/ViewController.swift:145:38: Cannot subscript a value of type '[ViewController.Point]' with an index of type 'ViewController.Point'

error 1:

> /Users/user/Desktop/proj/ViewController.swift:149:38: Cannot subscript a value of type '[ViewController.Point]' with an index of type 'ViewController.Point'

What is wrong with the code?
thanks!

Comment: You want to use `pointsArray.enumerated()` to get a tuple of index, value

Comment: thats right, but for his use case he don't need the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `element` is already a `Point` and not an index.

```
for element in pointsArray{
    distance = getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(point1: element, point2: myPoint) // fix here
    if (distance < minDist1) {
        minDist1 = distance;
        twoPoint[1] = twoPoint[0];
        twoPoint[0] = element; // fix here
    }
    else if (distance < minDist2) {
        minDist2 = distance;
        twoPoint[1] = element; // fix here
    }
}
```

PS:
take a loook also to [this question "Sort array by calculated distance in Swift"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199363/sort-array-by-calculated-distance-in-swift) for better calculation of distance. just sort the array by distance and then take the first from the array after it is sorted. thats more easy to do

Comment: That was a big help!
now its yelling in the first line /Users/user/Desktop/proj/PdacJobTest/ViewController.swift:137:47: Missing argument labels 'point1:point2' in call

Comment: then you not call it right it should be somehow:
`let twopoints = findNearsetPoints(pointsArray: myPointsArray , myPoint: myPoint )`

Comment: this is the problematic line: distance = getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(element, Point);

Comment: when you add labels you need to use the labels or mark the label with an `_` that you don't need the labels. call it: `distance = getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(point1: element, point2: myPoint);` and change it to `myPoint` instead of the class Name

Comment: just a note: you don'd need a `;` at the end of line in swift

Answer (score 1):

You declared `getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints` as taking named parameters.

With the current declaration, you need to call it using this syntax:

```
getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(point1: aPoint, point2: anotherPoint)
```

If you want to call it without labels on the parameters then you should redefine it like this:

```
func getDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(
  _ point1:Point , 
  _ point2:Point )->Double{
        return 5; //TODO
    }
```