# NSLayoutConstraint style for VFL

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language, uilayoutguide

> "V:|[v(>=height)]-0.0@highPriority-|"

What will be the constraint (NSLayoutConstraint style) for above VFL.

Perhaps its considering view height with `greaterThanEqual` & bottom constraint with `UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh`.

Something i used -

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
bottomConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint,bottomConstraint])
```

Comment: Please Read a tutorial how to ask a question on SO. Your question is not clear.

Comment: @MahendraGP he wants to convert VFL -> NSLayoutConstraints

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Initial Set up for Answer:

```
let parentView = self.view!

let childView = UIView()
childView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
parentView.addSubview(childView)
```

---

For given VFL:

> "V:|[v(>=height)]-0.0@highPriority-|"

---

### 1. VFL Implementation:

```
let height: CGFloat = 100
let priority: Int = 1000

//VFL (for vertical positioning and height of childView
parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v(>=\(height))]-0.0@\(priority)-|",
                                                         options: [],
                                                         metrics: nil,
                                                         views: ["v" : childView]))
```

---

## 2. NSLayoutConstraint Implementation:

The above VFL's `NSLayoutConstraint` equivalent is:

```
let height: CGFloat = 100

//VFL Equivalent: "V:|[v]"
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView,
                                       attribute: .top,
                                       relatedBy: .equal,
                                       toItem: parentView,
                                       attribute: .top,
                                       multiplier: 1,
                                       constant: 0)

//VFL Equivalent: "[v(>=height)]"
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView,
                                          attribute: .height,
                                          relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                                          toItem: nil,
                                          attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: height)

//VFL Equivalent: "[v]|" or "[v]-0.0-|"
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView,
                                          attribute: .bottom,
                                          relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: parentView,
                                          attribute: .bottom,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 0)
//Adding VFL Equivalent: @priority
bottomConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh

childView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
parentView.addConstraint(topConstraint)
parentView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
```

---

NOTE: The given VFL in your question only provides the `childView`s y position and height.
For width, add the constraints accordingly.

VFL Example for width would be:

```
parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v(100)]",
                                                         options: [],
                                                         metrics: nil,
                                                         views: ["v" : childView]))
```

---

Ref:

- [Apple's Autolayout Guide on VFL](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html)