# Find closest longitude and latitude in array from user location and Sorting array corresponding to shortest distance from one to another lat long

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationdistance

I have an Array with lat long and I want to sort array like **dijkstra algorithm** (to find the shortest distance from one to another location)

```
for i in 0..<(dataArray - 1) {
    let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: (dataArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "addressLatitude") as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude:  (dataArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "addressLongitude") as! CLLocationDegrees)
    let coordinate2 = CLLocation(latitude: (dataArray[i+1] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "addressLatitude") as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude:  (dataArray[i+1] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "addressLongitude") as! CLLocationDegrees)

    var distance: CLLocationDistance? = nil
    distance = coordinate1.distance(from: coordinate2)
    let kilometers = CLLocationDistance((distance ?? 0.0) / 1000.0)
    print(kilometers)
}
```

Comment: And you absolutely want to use the `dijkstra algorithm`, or using the `sort` of CocoaTouch is enough?

Comment: @Larme I want to calculate distance from current to closest  latlong, then New  closest to other closest lat long.. so on..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199363/sort-array-by-calculated-distance-in-swift ? And read documentation/samples on how using `sorted(by:)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all **shortest** needs to be relative to a certain point, so when you say shortest let's assume that you are talking about the user's current location so in the following code I'll describe assuming that there's a variable `var userLocation: CLLocation`

```
    let sorted = dataArray.sorted{ (a, b) -> Bool in
    let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: a["addressLatitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: a["addressLongitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
    let coordinate2 = CLLocation(latitude: b["addressLatitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: b["addressLongitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
    return coordinate1.distance(self.userLocation) > coordinate2.distance(self.userLocation)
}
```

where `let sorted` is having your dataArray sorted.